# Vi help problem with / in command mode

Tags: vim, vi

I have an issue with the `vi` text editor, when in command mode after I enter ":" and want to use "/", the forward slash does not come up. What I get is "< f2 >".

Comment: Star `vim` without your .vimrc: `vim -u NONE` - does the problem still occur?

Comment: Did you use the `/` from the numeric keypad or from the main keypad? What is your keyboard layout? What is your operating system? Are you running gvim, or vim in a terminal (which one?)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might have used numeric keypad. For me also, pressing  `/` in numeric pad shows `<F2>` in command line.

It is mapped by default.
You can type `:set termcap` and look for `t_K8`. That will show `<kDivide>`.

Solutions:

1) pressing `/` near to shift key instead of the other one.

2) setting termcap of `t_K8` to `/`.

3) Mapping `<kDivide>` to `/`.

4) Mapping `<F2`> to `/` in command line if it is the first character, like,

```
      :cnoremap <expr> <F2> (getcmdpos() == 1 ?  '/'. : '<F2>`
```